# Discord.js voiceStateUpdate not registering properly

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this piece code for discord.js copied from reddit which is supposed to detect if user has joined or left the channel but it sends leave notifications only no matter if someone joins or leaves the channel. About a year ago when I last tried this same code, it worked well, but now it doesn't.

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel

  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
     // User Joins a voice channel
    console.log('join');

  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
    // User leaves a voice channel
    console.log('leave');

  }
})
```

Has discord.js changed or what am I doing wrong? If you want the whole code, I can send it aswell.

Comment: `Has discord.js changed` > What version are you running right now?

Comment: @Variable Discord.js version 12.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Discord V12, `voiceChannel` is no longer a property of the GuildMember object. Use `voice` property instead.

```
guildMember.voice.channel;
```

There is a nice [guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#guildmember-voice) where you can find what has changed in **V12** when upgrading from **V11**.

Comment: That probably explains it, I'll try it out. I'm still a newbie on discord.js or programming in general, but I will try to figure it out.

Comment: No problem @MiQ. If you encounter any problems, just leave a comment and i'll try to reply as soon as I can.

Comment: I changed the `oldMember, newMember` to `oldState, newState` and changed `voiceChannel` to `voice.channel` and as the last thing I changed `undefined` to `null` and now it works perfectly! Thank you!